# Redshift: Analysis of all columns with null values in all the tables in a database

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

Need to find the counts of the null and not null values in all columns in all the tables in my database. With below query I can get the info for a single table.

```
SELECT
  'A' as col_name,
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(A) as nul_val,
  COUNT(A) as nnul_val 
FROM table1 
UNION
SELECT
  'B' as col_name,
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(B) as nul_val,
  COUNT(B) as nnul_val
FROM table1
```

I can query information_schema to get list of column names and tables names.

```
SELECT column_name, table_name from information_schema.columns;
```

How do I pass the column_name and table_name values from here to my main query? My database is Redshift and it has no provision for variables. Would most likely need to use python UDFs but I'm not sure how to write them for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python UDFs won't help you - they can only return a single value.

You will need to write a program external to Redshift to collect a list of tables and their columns, then run a query against each table and the table's specific columns.

By the way, there might be a slightly easier way to count the nulls, like this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL     THEN 1 END) as column1_null_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as column1_not_null_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL     THEN 1 END) as column2_null_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as column2_not_null_count
FROM table
```